# Discrete random variable which is memoryless

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

I need to find a discrete r.v. $Y$ on $(\mathbb{N}_0, 2^{\mathbb{N_0}})$ with the following property:
$$
\forall m,n \in \mathbb{N_0}:\mathbb{P}[Y\geq m+n |Y\geq m]=\mathbb{P}[Y\geq n]
$$
I have no clue whatsoever how to manage this and would appreciate your help.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memorylessness#Discrete_memorylessness

Comment: One of the standard examples of a discrete RV is famously memoryless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a random variable satisfying
$$
\mathbb P(Y\geq m+n)=\mathbb P(Y\geq n)\mathbb P(Y\geq m).
$$
Let $a_n=\mathbb P(Y\geq n)$. The above equation is equivalent to $a_{n+m}=a_na_m$, from which it follows by repeated application that $a_n=(a_1)^n$, which means that $Y$ has a geometric distribution.